# spark dataframe structured streaming write to s3a:// gives error 400

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, hdfs, spark-structured-streaming

I'm trying to stream data from kafka (json messages) and write it to aws s3 using apache spark's (2.4.0) structured streaming api.

But I get an exception from aws lib, without much detail.

I've tried writing on local fs and hdfs, it works properly.

For S3, I'm able to list files via hdfs cli using `hdfs dfs -ls s3://<bucket-name>/test/`

A snippet of what I'm trying to do

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
     .master("local[*]")
     .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
     .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", "xxxx")
     .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", "xxxx")
     .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com")
     .getOrCreate()

val df = spark.readStream.format("kafka")
               .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","localhost:9092")
               .option("subscribe", "test")
               .load()
// SOME ETL THEN

   df.writeStream
       .outputMode("append")
       .option("checkpointLocation", "s3a://<bucket-name>/test/")
       .format("json")
       .option("path", "s3a://<bucket-name>/test/")
       .start()
```

The Exception I get

> Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 400, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Error Code: null, AWS Error Message: Bad Request

Comment: @PabloLópezGallego I created a new bucket for Ireland region, it seems to be able to access s3, cause there were no errors only warnings also I can see the metadata created in the bucket. Although not able to write any of the stream data ( which I think must be a different problem).

Comment: Ok, sorry, I couldn't help you